# MLKIt TextRecognization - How to manipulate text blocks of a paragraph in an newspaper content

Tags: firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am developing an OCR application using MLKit Text Recognition. The results of OCR is good and also provides bouldingBox for every word.
**My question is I wanted to scan a newspaper with proper block detection technique**.
As I saw in the MLKit, It searches the text in plain horizontal manner but not giving exact portion of paragraphs. It mixed up the multiple paragraphs together and creates TextBlocks.

Hope you understand my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The next ML Kit release (in August) will have a brand-new version of the Text API that has drastic improvements in paragraphing. It should tackle most of these issues. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank for valuable time @Chrisito , Can you tell us what all the features and improvements taken in this latest release?.
This info will keep our attention towards the latest release.

Thanks.